# Error with mono while updating ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, updates, repository, mono

I'm kindly asking for your help. I'm trying to update with `sudo apt update` on Ubuntu 20.04, but I get this error message:
`E: The repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal/snapshots/2.6.3 Release' does not have a Release file.`
I find this command, `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and I run it. I found two things related to mono in /etc/apt/sources.list.d:

- mono-official-stable.list
- mono-official-stable.list.save

I tried to run `sudo add-apt-repository --remove mono-official-stable.list` but it did not work, When I try to update, the same error appears again: `E: The repository 'https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-focal/snapshots/2.6.3 Release' does not have a Release file.`
How can I deal with this issue and be able to update repos without getting that error. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: Hello, @user535733, thanks for your response, I went to the link, and in the case of the link you posted, they speak of ppa:mc3man/trusty-media, whereas in my case it is in this form mono-official-stable.list, can we put it in the form ppa? If not, then how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Whether or not you have the same PPA is irrelevant. That link explains the problem. When you *understand* the problem, then you will understand why you must disable or delete the relevant PPA, and how to do so safely.